# MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: notebooks

[image]

[image]
I'm trying to use WolframNotebookEmbedder.  When I place the javascript in my HTML I see the following error in the console (the notebook does not display): Note the meta-statement shown above is properly terminated [the line is very long]

[image]

Comment: This is more of a JS/WolframNotebookEmbedder issue than a Mathematica one so I think it unlikely you'll be able to get much help here. Try reaching out to WRI and telling them to inform Jan Poeschko

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. I will take your advice.